# Compilation Syntax Error

Tags: c++, syntax

I am trying to compile a card game project. Unfortunately I am stuck with a "expected ; before ( token" error, which I could not get my head around. Error occurs in the *player* header file, which is highlighted.

```
//player.h
#ifndef PLAYER
#define PLAYER
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "card.h"


using std::vector;

class player{
      public:
             card getHand(int); 
             vector <card> gethand();
             void printhand();
             int gethandsize(); 
             int givecard(deck&,int,int); //**ERROR OCCURS HERE**
             bool checkdecision(int* decision);
             bool compare(int decision, player& thief);
             void steal(card);
             void discard(int decision);

      protected:



      private:      
                    vector <card> h;
};
#endif

//player.cpp
#include "player.h"
player::player(){
}

vector <card> player::gethand(){
    return h;
}

card player::getHand(int num){
    return h[num];
}

int player::givecard(deck& pool, int hand_index, int &deck_index){
    card temp = pool.getd(deck_index);
    h.push_back(temp);
    pool.pop_back();
}

void player::printhand(){
    for(int a = 0; a<h.size(); a++){
        cout << h[a].rank_map << " of " << h[a].suit_map << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


bool player::checkdecision(int decision){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int a=0; a<h.size(); a++){
        if(h[a].rank != decision){ 
            ++counter;
        }
    }
    if(counter == h.size()){
        cout << "You don't have the card. Start again." << endl;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool player::compare(int decision, player& thief){
    card temp;
    int index = 0, initial_hand = h.size();
    for(int b = 0; b < initial_hand; b++){
        if(h[b].rank != decision){
            index++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < h.size(); i++){
        if(h[i].rank == decision){
            cout << "Steal!" << endl;
            temp = h[i];
            thief.steal(temp);
            h.erase(h.begin() + i);
            i--;
        }
    }
    if(index == initial_hand){
        return false;   
    }
    else if (index != initial_hand){return true;}
}

void player::discard(int decision){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < h.size(); k++){
        if(h[k].rank == decision){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if(counter == 4){
        for(int a = 0; a < h.size(); a++){
            if(h[a].rank == decision){
                h.erase(h.begin() + a );
                a--;
            }
        }
    }
}

void player::steal(card temp){
    h.push_back(temp);
}
int player::gethandsize(){
    return h.size();
}

player::~player(){}

//cardgames.h
#ifndef CARD_GAMES
#define CARD_GAMES
#include "player.h"
#include "deck.h"



class card_games{
      public:      
                   card_games();
                   void play();
                   void checkplayer(char thePlayer);
                   int convert(char);
                   void distribute();
                   void setgame(int);
                   void printhand();
                   deck getpool();
                   player getplayer(int);
                   ~card_games();

      protected:
              int num_player; //number of players
              int player_num; //player's turn    

      private:
              deck pool; //pool object
              player* p;     //array of players
};
#endif

//cardgames.cpp
#include "card_games.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

card_games::card_games(){}

void card_games::play(){
     char thePlayer;
     int temp; 
       cout << "How many players are playing?" << endl;
            cin >> thePlayer;
    checkplayer(thePlayer);
    temp = convert(thePlayer);
    setgame(temp);
    distribute();
}

void card_games::checkplayer(char thePlayer){
    if(thePlayer < 50 || thePlayer > 54 ){
        cout << "Invalid number of players. Please retry." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

int card_games::convert(char input){
    int value;
    player_num = 1;
    if(input== '2'){
        value = 2;
    }
    if(input== '3'){
        value =3;
    }
    if(input== '4'){
        value = 4;
    }
    if(input== '5'){
        value = 5;
    }
    if(input == '6'){
        value= 6;
    }
    return value;
}

void card_games::setgame(int temp){
     p = new player[temp];
     num_player = temp;
}

void card_games::distribute(){
     int temp;
     int deck_index = 51;
     for(int a=0; a < num_player; a++){ //player number
        for(int b=0; b < 7; b++){ // hand size
            p[a].givecard(pool, b, deck_index);
            --deck_index;
        }
    }
}

player card_games::getplayer(int temp){
       return p[temp];       
}

deck card_games::getpool(){
       return pool;              
}

card_games::~card_games(){
}
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: where does `deck` come from?

Comment: If the error occurs on that specific line then why are you showing us the rest of your program which has nothing to do with the error?

Comment: Because there could be something in the implementation that causes the error.

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing what's in `"card.h"`. I copy-and-pasted your `player.h`, commented out the `#include "card.h"` line and added definitions for `card` and `hand`, and it compiled without error. Are `card` and `deck` type names? You've posted way too much irrelevant code; please read http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype of givecard does not match the declared method:

```
 int givecard(deck&,int,int);
```

Should probably be:

```
 int givecard(deck&,int,int&);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: (I thought I had posted a comment here, but I don't see it now.) That's true, but it doesn't answer the question; the missing `&` wouldn't explain the syntax error message. This would be a good comment on the question, though.